# Como criar interface TypeScript que reflete estrutura firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firestore

Bom dia,

Estou recebendo dados do firebase firestore com uma estrutura que estou com dificuldades em representá-la como um model no TypeScript, ou seja, uma interface. Fiz uma representação em JSON para exemplificar a estrutura:

```
[
    {
      "20229622": [
        {
            "info": [
                {
                    "46468999": {
                        "taskName": "Project Management",
                        "totalTaskHours": "1589.4"
                    },
                    "78945556": {
                        "taskName": "Management",
                        "totalTaskHours": "988"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "done": [
                {
                    "46468999": {
                        "done": "True"
                    },
                    "78945556": {
                        "done": "False"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }

      ],
      "90220622": [
        {
            "info": [
                {
                    "46418909": {
                        "taskName": "Interface",
                        "totalTaskHours": "189"
                    },
                    "98940556": {
                        "taskName": "Backend",
                        "totalTaskHours": "90"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "done": [
                {
                    "46418909": {
                        "done": "True"
                    },
                    "98940556": {
                        "done": "False"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Minha maior dificuldade é em relação aos id's que são números gerados automaticamente pelo firestore. Peço que me ajudem a criar uma interface que reflete essa estrutura, ou me dê alguma dica, principalmente na questão dos id's.